# My laptop can't run Watch Dogs

Tags: watch-dogs

I have Samsung laptop `np550p5c-s01in`. My laptop configuration is:

- CPU: Intel i5-3210m
- RAM: 6 GB
- Graphics: nVidia GT650M DDR3-2GB with latest driver
- HDD: 1 TB
- Screen resolution: 1600*900
- OS: Windows 8.1

I had installed watch dogs on my laptop but when I start the game it can not respond without any type of error. When I look to the task manager the process of watch dogs created it uses the cpu 38% or nearer and then that process killed automatically why does it happen?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you do not meet the minimum system requirements in order to run the game.  In order for us to be able to help you, this requirement must be met.

Comment: He does actually meet the minimum requirements (except maybe his OS is x86, in which case he doesn't). He should be able to at least run the game and get to the main menu, if nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, your laptop does not meet the minimum hardware requirements.

> **Supported OS:** Windows Vista SP2 64bit, Windows 7 SP1 64bit, Windows 8 64bit
>
> **Processor:** Intel Core 2 Quad Q8400 @ 2.66Ghz or AMD Phenom II X4 940 @ 3.0Ghz
>
> **RAM:** 6 GB
>
> **Video Card:** 1024 VRAM DirectX 11 with Shader Model 5.0 (see supported list)
>
> **Sound Card:** DirectX 9 compatible Sound Card
>
> **This product supports 64-bit operating systems ONLY**
>
> [Source](http://www.pcgamer.com/au/2013/10/08/watch-dogs-system-requirements-announced-specify-64-bit-os-and-minimum-6-gb-of-ram/)

Although you have met the 6 GB of RAM, our [processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/67355/Intel-Core-i5-3210M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz-rPGA) only has a speed of 2.5Ghz, not meeting the 2.66Ghz requirement.

You also didn't mention whether you are running a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows 8.

If you are running a 32-bit OS, Watchdogs will not run.

Comment: Wouldn't he have to be running 64bit to allow the usage of 6GB of RAM?

Comment: @NathanTaylor: It's [possible](http://www.pallab.net/2009/12/30/enable-more-than-4gb-memory-in-windows-vista-7/) to have more than 4GB of RAM if you enable PAE and patch your kernel... but that's extremely uncommon :) Regardless, applications would still be limited to 2-3GB each

Comment: The CPU is good enough (i5-3210m is more powerful than Core 2 Quad Q8400), but the graphics card is not (according to Steam's minimum system requirements compared to Passmark's benchmarks). Processor clock speed is not the only factor.

Comment: He should be able to at least RUN the game on that spec (assuming he's running an x64 OS). The CPU clock on that particular model increases frequency up to 3.1 GHz when necessary, and it's certainly faster than min requirements.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Caleb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/77290/caleb)'s answer you need to know that Ubisoft has not managed to optimize Watchdogs for older systems yet. Even on my high-end-pc it leads to problems concerning FPS, no matter what graphic settings I use. The game is just not perfectly optimized yet...unfortunately.

Comment: Understatement of the year.